# Invertibility of MDP policy evaluation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, control-theory

For infinite horizon MDP, to compute the value function for a policy $\pi$ we can use the matrix equation:

$V(S) = R + \gamma P*V(S)$ where $P$ is a transition probability matrix and $0<\gamma<1$ leading to the equation $(I-\gamma P)*V(S) = R$,

I want to know how we know $I-\gamma P$ is invertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a telescoping sum argument, we have for all positive integers $k$
$$(I-\gamma P)\sum_{i=0}^k \gamma^i P^i = I - \gamma^{k+1} P^{k+1}$$ 
where we define $\gamma^0P^0$ to be the identity matrix $I$.  Taking a limit as $k\rightarrow\infty$ and using the fact that $0<\gamma<1$ and all entries of $P^{k+1}$ are always between 0 and 1 gives
$$(I-\gamma P)\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \gamma^i P^i = I$$ 
and so 
$$(I-\gamma P)^{-1} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \gamma^i P^i$$

Comment: Thanks, is it straightforward to show the composition of transition matrix always has entry between 0 and 1?

Comment: Yes, $P_1P_2...P_k$ for any probability transition matrices is itself a probability transition matrix.  Or you can prove it by induction from the base case $k=2$.